# Start a browser, any modern browser, from win 7 command line at a preset geometry. Is it possible

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, browser

I am in need of writing a batch script, which will start "A" browser session at a certain location on the screen and at a certain size and display a locally stored and  very simple HTML file. I am not picky about browser type. The html document is nothing fancy, no dynamic content. Just a scrolling marquee when there exists a file.

Is it possible to open any one of major browsers, that is available on win 7 platform, at a location (x,y coordinates in pixels) and at a certain size ? This will be used by an elderly person, who can close any open window by clicking the X sign on the right top corner but other thna that, quite computer illiterate and the screen used always occupied by other content with a bit of space available near the bottom, to scroll this message.

If it si possible, could you please tell me the syntax of the command to run in the batch file ?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible in batch (the only options with the `start` command are Minimised/Maximised).

This will probably be possible in C# though. Even better, if you dont want the browser to be fancy like you said, you could easily make a browser in C#, and make it take a number of parameters which would adjust sign and postition. If all you need is for the user to observe a html document and then close the browser I would seriously recommend you learn some basic C# and make this, or post another question presenting you're conundrum tagged `C#`.

Mona

Answer (score 0):

You can place your html content into an .hta file that will be handled by mshta.exe. This is a container for the web browser control, but running with the security of a desktop application. So, you can include the required code (javascript, vbscript or any other active scripting engine available on the machine) to access the window object and move / resize it as needed.